# Programmatically submit form with "submit" events

Tags: javascript

I would like to submit a form with vanilla JS, but still trigger submit events. Basically the same as pressing the "submit" button.

`HTMLFormElement.submit()` skips the "submit" event so it does not work for me.

`HTMLFormElement.requestSubmit()` seems like it would do what I want, but it's browser support is very poor. I would like Chrome/Safari/Firefox/Edge support.

Comment: Can you please explain the exact use-case? Why don't you use the standard form submission mechanism?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit)

Comment: Could you not click the submit button using js?  That way it should post the form and hit the on submit event

Comment: @Reynadan No, not really. All of the top answers there do exactly what the OP does *not* want.

Comment: There various form-requestsubmit polyfills. Have you looked at them? Their implementation seems quite trivial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To programmatically submit a form and still trigger a "submit" event, *besides using `.requestSubmit()`*, would be to use `.click()` method on the "submit" button. In the example below are the following:

- A `<form>` that will post it's data to a live test server. The test server's response will be displayed in an `<frame>` located after the `<form>`.
- A `<button>` outside of the `<form>` and has no `form` attribute assigned to it either. This button is isolated from the `<form>` but it will still trigger a "submit" event indirectly since it is registered to the "click" event and the event handler will programmatically click the "submit" button.
- Note, the `<button>` is not necessary to use the `.click()` method, it can be invoked by other means like any other method or function.

***Click the Trigger button***

```
<button class='trigger'>Trigger</button>
```

```js
const trigger = document.querySelector('.trigger');

trigger.onclick = e => document.querySelector('form button').click();
```

```css
.trigger {
  vertical-align: top
}
```

```html
<form id='UI' action='https://httpbin.org/post' method='POST' target='response'>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Programmatically Submit a Form</legend>
    <input name='test' value='TEST'>
    <button name='send'>Send</button>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<hr>
<button class='trigger'>Trigger</button>
<iframe name='response'></iframe>
```

Comment: I was hoping that this would be possible without altering the DOM. Feels a bit contrived, but it might be the only way. );

Comment: The DOM doesn't need to be altered at all, I just added a button for demonstration purposes. You can do the same thing by just running this alone: `document.forms[0].elements.ID_or_Name_of_Submit_Button.click()` or `document.querySelector('[type="submit"]').click()`, or.... a thousand other possibilities...`.click()`. Unless of course you never had a submit button in the first place but then that'd be bad UX.